# Unable to modify ulimit

Tags: process, ulimit

I am on `Ubuntu 18.04`

Trying to modify max number of processes (hard limit) via the following command, and getting the respective error:

```
$ ulimit -H -u 500
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

In the mean time ...

```
$ ulimit -Hu
46955
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to lower the soft limit before you can lower the hard limit.

You can see the differences between them using the relevant flags. For example:

```
$ ulimit -Su
900

$ ulimit -Hu
900
```

Here, my hard limit and soft limit are the same. If I attempt to lower my soft limit, it succeeds:

```
$ ulimit -Su 800
$ ulimit -Su
800
```

But if I try to lower my hard limit below the soft limit, it fails:

```
$ ulimit -Hu 700
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

So, I first need to lower my soft limit so that I can set the new hard limit:

```
$ ulimit -Su 700
$ ulimit -Hu 700
$ ulimit -Su
700
$ ulimit -Hu
700
```

Comment: Why when am I trying to lower the soft limit I get the following? `$ ulimit -Su 100
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
`

Comment: @pkaramol how many processes (including threads) do you have running currently (e.g. `ps -u $USER -L | wc -l`)? Perhaps you are trying to set the limit too low.

Comment: Am I not setting them this way just for the current shell? The current shell has none other than itself.

Comment: What does `ulimit -Su` says before you're trying to set it?